# Getting a foreign key constraing when trying to insert row into DB Browser

Tags: javascript, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have created the following tables with JS:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.sqlite');

db.serialize(function() {
  db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Artist` ( ' +
        '`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
        '`name` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
        '`date_of_birth` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
        '`biography` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
        '`is_currently_employed` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, ' +
        'PRIMARY KEY(`id`) )');

  db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Series` ( ' +
        '`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
        '`name` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
        '`description` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
        'PRIMARY KEY(`id`) )');

  db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Issue` ( ' +
        '`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
        '`name` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
        '`issue_number` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
        '`publication_date` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
        '`artist_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
        '`series_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
        'PRIMARY KEY(`id`), ' +
        'FOREIGN KEY(`artist_id`) REFERENCES `Artist`(`id`), ' +
        'FOREIGN KEY(`series_id`) REFERENCES `Series`(`id`) )');
});
```

`Artist` and `Series` table work fine and I'm able to update them and insert rows into them, but I can't seem to enter any data into the cells for the `Issues` using "DB Browser". I'm not sure if there are some settings in it that I need to modify, because I can't even edit the cells to insert rows into them. I get the following error:

> Error adding record:
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (INSERT INTO `Issue`(`id`,`name`,`issue_number`,`publication_date`,`artist_id`,`series_id`) VALUES (1,'',0,'',0,0);)

Which basically says that no information was stored in the table cells when I tried to create a new record.

Comment: Do you have entries in those tables with id's of 0?

Comment: And what's with all the backticks? This is sqlite, not mysql... and none of those column or table names need escaping anyways.